# TIBCO amx administrator page is not able to load plugins

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works, tibco-topic

I am trying to start my TIBCO amxadministrator and the page is not able to load plugins and it is empty except the title (please refer image).

I am facing this issue long time, any idea how to resolve.

[image]

Thanks,
Rudra

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to open URL in any other browser as well?

Also, try to restart the instance once and check if you are still facing the same issue.